# a way to figure out what blocks my click event/handler (msDropDown)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the msdropdown library and added console.log on the has_handler (jquery.dd.3.5.3.js) and noticed the reason my dropdown isn't working when I click on it (only works through other means like using the input field to filter), that the click handler is not working.

Since I can't figure out what prevents/overrides it, I was hoping that there is a way to trace the hanlder action and see, what prevents it.

```
jquery.dd.3.5.3.js
 var has_handler = function (name) {
        //True if a handler has been added in the html.
        var evt = {byElement: false, byJQuery: false, hasEvent: false};
        var obj = $("#" + element);
        console.log(name);
        try {
            //console.log(obj.prop("on" + name) + " "+name);
            if (obj.prop("on" + name) !== null) {
                evt.hasEvent = true;
                evt.byElement = true;
            };
        } catch(e) {
            //console.log(e.message);
        }
        // True if a handler has been added using jQuery.
        var evs;
        if (typeof $._data === "function") { //1.8
            evs = $._data(obj[0], "events");
        } else {
            evs = obj.data("events");
        };
        if (evs && evs[name]) {
            evt.hasEvent = true;
            evt.byJQuery = true;
        };
        return evt;
```

it shows the mouseover, mouse down, double click etc... just not the normal "click"

[image: console.log]

some extra info: I'm using jquery-2.2.4.min

Comment: there's also the onclick subtle entry point... it's an attribute of the element containing the js string that will be evaluated when the event occurs. But it's just to cut the hair in four. And just as a further extra info, what happens if you decide arbitrarily to add a click event handler on that element from console after the page was far load? does the handler gets executed in that case? Maybe the order in which you load your js asset or how they get executed that makes the difference erasing any handler registered before

Comment: i tried for example `$('#msdrpdd20_msdd').on('click', function(){console.log('test')})` and after clicking on it, it does throw the test string in the console, but i dont think js load order is wrong, since i use it on another page just the same and it works. i will take a deeper look in this tho once again, thx for the response

Comment: @DiegoDeVita i only have 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="/test/sysinc/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" ></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/gprsv2/sysinc/js/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/test/sysinc/js/jquery.dataTables-1.10.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/test/sysinc/js/jquery.dd-3.5.3.js"></script>` 
I don't see them as being in the wrong order (even tried multiple ones)

Comment: Also examined your latest comments.. yes I agree. I mean at first I was just throwing everything I could come up with.. even if farfetched. if you could verify that the latest listener was correctly added from console and correctly invoked when the event occurred; and you can be sure there's some click event listener supposed to be added to the element at some point in your logic and that at some point later got detached; something happened.. and I was speculating that the library overriding the dropdowns maybe had a role if your original listener were added earlier

Comment: the problem is that we are going by trial and error... formally speaking this question should have the information needed for the problem to be replicated. If you please just share the code needed to render the dropdown that is causing the problem, it will be possible to experiment each one on its own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, i gave the select the "data-event=''" attribute which, caused no errors but prevented the dropdown from happening.